# why raspberry pi got two 5v pins?

Tags: pi-2

If I understand it correctly: the two 5v pins are inner connected, so what's the purpose to design two 5v pins, please share a scenario that requires to use both 5v pins, thanks

Comment: Same reason it has 5 Gnd pins

Comment: @Milliways 8 ground pins actually :) and multiple 3V3 of course

Comment: There is many power supply to plug many things. However, as the power supply is giving 5.1V 3.0A DC output, if you plug many 3/5V, as the power remains the same, the current drops so if you need a certain power, you will need an extra power supply that your Raspberry cannot give.

Comment: why would there be a scenario that **requires** the use of both 5 V pins?

Answer (score 2):

It is commonplace to use external modules with the RPi, such as GPS receivers, real time clocks, fans, modems, and many other types of devices.

Many/most of these are designed to be powered from 5V DC.  Having a couple of 5V pins means that you may use the RPi to supply that power to the module(s).

Additionally, some other modules may run on 3.3V so there are also two 3.3V pins on the RPi header for that purpose.